# When/why are libstdc++ and libc++ symbols incompatible?

Tags: c++, libstdc++, abi, libc++, object-files

Setup:

`test.cpp`

```
#include <set>
#include <string>

void common_config_file_iterator(const std::set<std::string>& allowed_options) {}
```

`include.cpp`

```
#include <set>
#include <string>

void common_config_file_iterator(const std::set<std::string>&) noexcept;

int main() {
    std::set<std::string> set;
    common_config_file_iterator(set);
    return 0;
}
```

`test.sh`

```
clang++-7 test.cpp -c -O3 -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -o test.o
g++-8 test.o include.cpp -O3 -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -o test
```

Output:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "common_config_file_iterator(std::set<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&)", referenced from:
      _main in ccWoGgrX.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So I did `nm -g test.o`:

```
0000000000000000 T __Z27common_config_file_iteratorRKNSt3__13setINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEENS_4lessIS6_EENS4_IS6_EEEE
```

According to [demangler.com](https://demangler.com/), it means:

```
common_config_file_iterator(std::__1::set<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > const&)
```

[Libc++ says](https://libcxx.llvm.org/#goals):

> [Features and Goals:] ABI compatibility with gcc's libstdc++ for some low-level features such as exception objects, rtti and memory allocation.

So, is the problem `std::allocator<char>`?

Note that I use the macOS assembler.

Curiosity caused by [this issue](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/3228) and [boost/program-options](https://github.com/boostorg/program_options/blob/4b81beaaa995026ebdc032bfe809f64a5056ce88/src/config_file.cpp#L23).

Comment: Goal may mean that they don't agree at this stage?

Comment: noexcept is missing, it is part of the function signature.

Comment: @Hans but is `noexcept` also part of the ABI?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher no, it means "some low-level features such as exception objects, rtti and memory allocation" not `std::set` and `std::string`.

Comment: @rubenvb it's not part of the mangled name, but is part of the type. But that's irrelevant here. The problem is much less subtle than that.

Comment: Did you maybe read the goal as "except for" instead of just "for"? You disable RTTI and exceptions and worry about `std::allocator` as if you think that exception objects, rtti and memory allocation are the things that are *not* compatible, when in fact they are the **only things** that are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, is the problem `std::allocator<char>`?

What? No. It's **everything** in your example.

The doc you quoted clearly says the goal is compatibility for "low-level features such as exception objects, rtti and memory allocation".

`std::set` and `std::string` are not "low-level features such as exception objects, rtti and memory allocation". They are very definitely not compatible between libc++ and libstdc++, which are completely different libraries with completely different implementations.

The compatible pieces are things like `std::type_info` and `std::exception` (and the derived exception types in `<stdexcept>`) because those are part of the basic language runtime. Anything above that, such as containers, strings, algorithms, I/O, locales etc. is not compatible.